# regarding overlaying a logic array on a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

There is a code segment, the train is a dataframe with shape `(10000,24)`. I don't quite understand the line of code `X_train = train[msk].iloc[:,features]` in specific. What does `train[mask]` aims to do?

```
train = pandas.read_csv(train_file)
msk = np.random.rand(len(train)) < 0.8
features = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
X_train = train[msk].iloc[:,features]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very inefficient means of splitting the dataset `train` into approximately a 80-20 split. It creates a boolean array of approximately 80% true and 80% false.

To illustrate, take this toy example:

```
# Create a train dataframe
train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,4)))
>>> train
          0         1         2         3
0  0.514717  0.570628  0.315088  0.610563
1  0.070222  0.392518  0.222532  0.316044
2  0.002166  0.628661  0.871658  0.919967
3  0.487811  0.948827  0.862359  0.288661
4  0.473024  0.143987  0.318512  0.180763
5  0.438993  0.060274  0.603310  0.643926
6  0.115308  0.797109  0.716390  0.385135
7  0.591124  0.772243  0.185121  0.775700
8  0.994233  0.126579  0.560132  0.424696
9  0.417475  0.778452  0.403525  0.510491

# Create your mask
mask = np.random.rand(10) < 0.8

>>> mask
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,
        True])
```

As you can see, mask is *approximately* 80% True, because it creates an array of random uniform values between 0 and 1, and then finds where those values are over `0.8`. Since they're random uniform distributed, about 80% of the values will be above `0.8`.

Then, your code masks the selected columns of your dataframe with those booleans, selecting those rows where the indices are equal to `True` in the mask:

```
# Select relevant features
features = [0,1,2]

# Mask the relevant features of train dataframe with your mask
X_train = train[mask].iloc[:,features]
>>> X_train
          0         1         2
0  0.514717  0.570628  0.315088
1  0.070222  0.392518  0.222532
2  0.002166  0.628661  0.871658
3  0.487811  0.948827  0.862359
7  0.591124  0.772243  0.185121
8  0.994233  0.126579  0.560132
9  0.417475  0.778452  0.403525
```

Notice how the rows selected are only those whose indices are `True` in the mask. It omits rows 4, 5, and 6 because those indices are `False` in your mask. Also, it only selects the columns that we chose in `features`.

A much better way to do this would be to use `train_test_split` from `sklearn`. Or you could just use `train[features].sample(frac=0.8)`, it will do the same thing, but at least guarantee an 80% split:

```
>>> train[features].sample(frac=0.8)
          0         1         2
3  0.487811  0.948827  0.862359
7  0.591124  0.772243  0.185121
2  0.002166  0.628661  0.871658
9  0.417475  0.778452  0.403525
6  0.115308  0.797109  0.716390
1  0.070222  0.392518  0.222532
4  0.473024  0.143987  0.318512
0  0.514717  0.570628  0.315088
```